# Why is there no fold' method?

Tags: haskell, big-o, lazy-evaluation, fold, monoids

I noticed that the Foldable class contains fold, foldl, foldr, foldl', and foldr', but there's no fold' (for strict monoidal folds)

How can I emulate the behavior of fold' with an IntMap (which is implemented as a tree, but doesn't give direct access to the internal nodes).

---

<s>Motivation:</s>

In particular, if I have an IntMap containing M IntMap's of size K (with total size N = M*K), I'd like to union them in O(N * log(M)) big-O running time.  Something like:

```
unionMaps :: IntMap (IntMap a) -> IntMap a
unionMaps = fold'
```

This would work because IntMap is an instance of Monoid with mappend defined as union.  Note that in general, using foldl' or foldr' is theoretically slower since it requires Omega(N * log N) worst-case running time.  Admittedly, this is probably an insignificant difference in practice, but I'm pedantic enough to care about theoretically optimal bounds

---

Oops, the above is wrong.  I went over it more carefully and now I realize it doesn't matter whether you use fold or foldl or foldr, the running time will be in O(N * log(M)).  So I no longer have any motivation for this question.

Comment: With `IntMap` elements, what would the difference even be between `fold` and a hypothetical `fold'`? `union` is spine-strict. It will perform the entire tree's worth of unions at the same time, when the result is demanded.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that.  I guess in general I can get the same result if I use a monoid for which mappend is strict in its arguments.  Is there an easy way to take a monoid and replace it with an identical one which is strict in its arguments?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could write a couple newtype wrappers for forcing their inputs - one for WHNF, the other for NF, for instance.  Then `foldMap` would apply the wrappers and do the monoidal combining all at once.

Comment: Actually, I've been thinking about it and I realize that my running-time analysis only applies if IntMaps are not only height-balanced, but also weight-balanced.  I don't think this is guaranteed, so probably the best approach is to extract the values out to a list and then write a smarter unionsWith function.

Comment: To be ideal on merge costs, you'd want to use something like the Huffman algorithm. But then you introduce additional bookkeeping that may well outweigh the merge cost savings. Have fun!

Comment: Nope, I got it wrong again.  I'm going over it more carefully and it looks like whether you use foldl or fold, the running time is always O(N log  M)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any library with the full `Foldable` `fold'`, to have an answer to the basic question, I wrote up some code for @Carl's suggestion from the comments above (WHNF only):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable

newtype StrictM m = StrictM { getStrict :: m }

instance Monoid m => Monoid (StrictM m) where
    mempty = StrictM mempty
    mappend (StrictM !x) (StrictM !y) = StrictM (mappend x y)

fold' :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => t m -> m
fold' = getStrict . foldMap StrictM
```